# How to reproduce LGBM (lightGBM) poisson loss in customized objective function

Tags: python, customization, poisson, lightgbm, objective-function

In my regression problem, when using LGBM's built-in poisson loss, I got very good model performance. Now I'm trying to reproduce LGBM's poisson loss in my customized objective function.

Here's the LGBM's source code of its poission function: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/7076cb8a3ac3a7b32dcf37be5593dddf27bf7f16/src/objective/regression_objective.hpp#L446
`max_delta_step=0.7` is configured here: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/7076cb8a3ac3a7b32dcf37be5593dddf27bf7f16/include/LightGBM/config.h#L792

Therefore, when creating customized objective function, my understanding for poission loss can be written as:

```
max_delta_step = 0.7
grad_poisson = np.exp(y_pred) - y_true
hess_poisson = np.exp(y_pred + max_delta_step)
```

But using this code without changing any other settings in LGBM, I got much worse model performance....

Does anyone know how to reproduce LGBM's poission loss in a customized objection function?

Comment: when you say `using this code without changing any other settings in LGBM`, does that mean that you have found a set of hyperparameters before using such settings and now, after changing the objective function, you keep the same set? if so, then this is a mistake and you should run your search again

Comment: The model params should be the same here. Cuz one was using LGBM built in poisson loss, the other is using my implemented poisson loss